# cmake failed catkin_pkg

Tags: ros, pythonpath, catkin-pkg

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I'm going through the ROS tutorials and am stuck at creating a workspace (http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/Tutorials/create_a_workspace).

When I try and run catkin_make, I keep getting the following

```
ImportError: "from catkin_pkg.package import parse_package" failed: No module named catkin_pkg.package
Make sure that you have installed "catkin_pkg", it is up to date and on the PYTHONPATH.
CMake Error at /opt/ros/hydro/share/catkin/cmake/safe_execute_process.cmake:11 (message):
execute_process(/home/shivam/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/bin/python
"/opt/ros/hydro/share/catkin/cmake/parse_package_xml.py"
"/opt/ros/hydro/share/catkin/cmake/../package.xml"
"/home/shivam/catkin_ws/build/catkin/catkin_generated/version/package.cmake")
  returned error code 1
Call Stack (most recent call first):
/opt/ros/hydro/share/catkin/cmake/catkin_package_xml.cmake:63 (safe_execute_process)
/opt/ros/hydro/share/catkin/cmake/all.cmake:142 (_catkin_package_xml)
/opt/ros/hydro/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:20 (include)
CMakeLists.txt:52 (find_package)

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
Invoking "cmake" failed
```

**However, catkin_pkg is installed AND on my PYTHON PATH**

```
echo $PYTHONPATH 
/opt/ros/hydro/lib/python2.7/dist-packages:/usr/share/pyshared/catkin_pkg
```

Also, EXTREMELY SORRY that I fail at pasting dialog from the terminal on here.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/126471/cmake-failed-catkin_pkg/) by [mr_d](https://answers.ros.org/users/11661/mr_d/) on ROS Answers with karma: 166 on 2014-02-05

Post score: 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

resolved using

```
pip install catkin_pkg
```

I'm using EPD, and the package was installed on a different Python

---

Originally posted by [mr_d](https://answers.ros.org/users/11661/mr_d/) with karma: 166 on 2014-02-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 9

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2014-02-05**:
You should only install packages from PIP when you are on a platform which does not use Debian packages. Otherwise install the package "python-catkin-pkg".

**Comment by [rong](https://answers.ros.org/users/23645/rong/) on 2015-08-20**:
It works for me:)

**Comment by [girayuzun](https://answers.ros.org/users/24517/girayuzun/) on 2017-03-08**:
thank you. It worked

**Comment by [Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/29757/moore/) on 2017-03-20**:
Thanks, it works for me

**Comment by [alexe](https://answers.ros.org/users/30056/alexe/) on 2017-04-17**:
this does not solve the issue, `catkin_pkg` is already installed with pip in my case and i still get the above error.

**Comment by [Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/29757/moore/) on 2017-04-18**:
Have you installed anaconda? If yes, maybe you should commet the anaconda path in .bashrc

**Comment by [MadeMyMark](https://answers.ros.org/users/64085/mademymark/) on 2020-11-25**:
Solved my issue as well.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

pip3 install catkin_pkg works for me.

---

Originally posted by [waschbaer00](https://answers.ros.org/users/34002/waschbaer00/) with karma: 41 on 2018-03-09

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1